# Configuration for JUnit test execution on multiple environments

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, maven-3, junit4

I have a Java project containing JUnit tests that needs to be run on different test environments (Dev, Staging, etc.) via Jenkins.

The solution that I currently have to build the project on the different environments and to to pass the url, username and the password to the test runner is to load specific property files for each environment, in the POM file. The property file will be set for each environment via the Maven build command:

> mvn clean install -DappConfig=/src/test/resouces/integration.environment.properties

in pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <appConfig>${app.config}</appConfig>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

In JUnit test runner class:

```
public class BoGeneralTest extends TestCase {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected BoHomePage boHomePage;
    protected static Properties systemProps;
    String url = systemProps.getProperty("Url");
    String username = systemProps.getProperty("Username");
    String password = systemProps.getProperty("Password");
    int defaultWaitTime = Integer.parseInt(systemProps.getProperty("waitTimeForElements"));
    String regUsername = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5);

    final static String appConfigPath = System.getProperty("appConfig");

    static {
        systemProps = new Properties();
        try {

            systemProps.load(new FileReader(new File(appConfigPath)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem with this configuration is that now the individual tests can't be run separately via Eclipse, because they expect to receive `appConfig` from maven and I'm getting NullPointerException.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need env setup for unit tests. A unit test should mock all dependencies and not depends on environments. If you are trying to execute integration test then you should take care of environments.

Comment: I have a set of test cases running against web site, so they need as  parameters url, login name and password

Comment: You can run your tests with Eclipse just set the java system property like -DappConfig="some location"

Comment: These are integration tests and for such purposes you should use the maven-failsafe-plugin instead. Having different environment you should have a separate maven project to do the integration testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precondition for running a single test is having a Run Configuration for each test case that will specify the default execution environment. Please note that this setting has to be done locally per test case.

In the Eclipse Arguments tab/VM Arguments filed the VM parameter has to be specified:

```
-DappConfig=src/test/resources/pp1.environment.properties
```

It holds the path to the respective property file having the environment login details.

There are five property files defined under src/test/resources source folder of the project:

```
environment1.properties
environment2.properties
environment3.properties
environment4.properties
environment5.properties
```

Answer (score -1):

WHITE BOX TESING:

UnitTests should test the unit of work and not depend on dependencies. The general rule is to mock dependencies and stub external systems so you have a safe environment to test.

IntegrationTests should somehow inject the real dependencies in a safe environement and do their tests.

BLACK BOX TESTING:

FunctionalTests is what i suppose you want to achieve. Usually you can use the same config from the integration tests, bundle all the automated tests in the projects pom and on every mvn clean isntall execute atomaticly the tests. The general flow is to startup a servlet container in the pre-integration-test phase and do your test against it. You should always test from the user perspective.